# Restrict <div>’s width to its content when it contains items wrapped in columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to add the items in the container from top to bottom and left to right to display items in several columns.
Here is the code what I'm working on.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#container .item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

When I set the `display` property as `inline-flex` the container does include only a single column, but not all the columns. If I set the `display` property as `flex`, the container width is larger than the total width of all the columns.

Here is the image what I need for better understanding.
[image: List items from top to bottom and left to right]

How can I make container width the same with the content width?

Comment: tried `width: min-content;` already?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: other thing, can you make a drawing of the intended layout? I guess that grid might be a better solution to what you try

Comment: i uploaded the image in the description.

Comment: This is a bug in both Chrome and Firefox. There are some workarounds scattered in the chrome bug https://crbug.com/507397. The simplest might be to specify a width on the flexbox like mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a solution using [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) via `display: inline-grid`.

`grid-template-rows: repeat(3, max-content)` means there should be three rows, each `max-content` high. I used `max-content` instead of `1fr` because when I tried using `1fr`, the second container had empty space at the bottom, making the container three rows tall. `max-content` seems to fix this by collapsing those rows when there is no item inside them.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, max-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#container .item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

Also, if the `margin: 10px` you added to `#container .item` was just for adding margin *between* the Flex items, you can now replace it with `gap: 10px` in `#container`.

Finally, the `inline` in `display: inline-grid` may cause you trouble due to the whitespace between elements being rendered as text. If this causes trouble you should be able to use `display: grid` instead, then wrap both containers in another `div` with `display: flex`.